# How to control the values inside a node list?

Tags: javascript, nodes

I have a node list that contains input text values,I'm trying to to oblige the user to input only numeric and alphabetic characters **Without RegEx**.I've tried to use the '.codeCharAt' function but no use. Here's my code

```
function verif(){
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]");
for (var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++)
    var value=nodes[i]
    if (value.charCodeAt(i)<48 ||value.charCodeAt(i)>57  ){
        alert("Alphabetic and numeric values only")
        Return false;
    }

}
```

**UPDATE*: After @blex's help and some of my additions it now works,here's the final code

```
function verif(){
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]");
for (var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++)
    var value=nodes[i].value
    for(var j =0;j<value.length;j++){
        if ((value.charCodeAt(j)<48 ||value.charCodeAt(j)>57) && ("A">=value[j].toLowerCase() && "Z">=value[j].toLowerCase())  ){
            console.log("Numeric and alphabetic values")
    }
    

    

}}
```

Comment: `var value=nodes[i]` ▶ You probably meant to write `var value=nodes[i].value;`. Also, for the first input (`i=0`), you are checking the first char. For the second input (`i=1`), you are checking the second char, and so on. You might want to nest a second loop in there, to check all chars. Also, `return` does not start with an upper case `R`

Answer (score 0):

Made a few changes to the code to get it working according to your logic. I suggest reviewing the documentation as you code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

 <form>
  <legend><h1>login</h1></legend>
   user: <input type="text" name="text" onchange="return verif();">
   
   <legend><h1>Text</h1></legend>
   Addr: <input type="text" id="Email"  value="kdkd" onchange="return verif();">
</form>


<script>
function verif() {
  alert(">> " + " [in verif()]");
  let nodes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]");
  let val = nodes[0].value  // array of input text
  let len = val.length
  alert("Value length>> " + len)
  for (let i=0; i<len; i++) {
    alert("char>> " + val.charAt(i))
    if (val.charAt(i)<'a' || val.charAt(i)>'z'  ) {
        alert("Alphabetic and numeric values only")
        return false;
    }
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```